Benchmark Neural Networks on High-Dimensional Functions
For a personal project, I am interested in benchmarking certain neural network architectures in the context of high-dimensional function approximation. Specifically, I am interested in continuous, smooth, Hölder, and Sobolev functions defined on $[0,1]^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Does anyone know if a standard list of high-dimensional functions is commonly used in the literature to benchmark such models? For example, in the optimization literature, there is a standard list of functions, such as the ones found here, to benchmark various optimization algorithms.

If no such list is available, how should one construct a representative list of functions? This choice will introduce an inductive bias in the problem, so I'd like to ensure the list is as representative as possible.


Thanks!

Not an answer, but I don't have credentials to put in comments.
I might be uninformed, but representative of the various functions spaces you mentioned.  Those sets are defined by restriction properties.  How does one characterize or sample them? I am curious.  I might never have heard about that. Although I might think that a basis spanning the space might be a way?
Or if they have metrics?  Sorry, not of much help. But curious about more background implied in your question. I can delete, this is not appropriate.
